# SyntaxError using `with open...`

Tags: python, python-2.7, with-statement

There are several questions on SO that seem to deal with my problem. However, they all seem to be caused by using a pre-2.6 version of Python. Which is not the case here. I appreciate any help tracking down the cause of this.

I get a Syntax Error when I try to use a `with open() as f` construct.

Here's the code (test.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
print sys.version

fname = "/tmp/test.txt"

open(fname, 'a').close()

with open(fname, 'a') as fh
  fh.write("test")
```

Here's the output:

```
$ ./test.py
  File "./test.py", line 10
    with open(fname, 'a') as fh
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python version being used:

```
$ /usr/bin/env python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02)
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.4m /usr/bin/python3.3 /usr/bin/python3.3m /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.4 /usr/lib/python3.3 /usr/lib/python3.5 /usr/lib/python2.7 /etc/python3.4 /etc/python /etc/python3.3 /etc/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.4 /usr/local/lib/python3.3 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

My system info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ... 4.2.0-27-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 04:49:08 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks!

Comment: Put ':' as with open(fname, 'a') as fh: and You should delete this question

Comment: `open(name, 'a').close()` can be removed. You don't gain anything by opening (or attempting to open) and immediately closing the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `:` after your `with` statement

```
with open(fname, 'a') as fh:
  fh.write("test")
```

Comment: How utterly stupid of me! Thanks for pointing that out. You made my day.

Comment: You wouldn't believe how long I've been staring at this, haha. LOL!